# Transformation of Yang Mills field

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gauge-theory, field-theory, gauge-invariance, yang-mills

The transformation of Yang Mills field is given by:

$$A'_\mu= U A_\mu U^{-1}-\frac{i}{g} (\partial_\mu U) U^{-1},~~~~~~~~(1)$$

Where: $A_\mu = A_\mu^i \frac{\tau_i}{2}, U= 1 -  \frac{i}{2} \tau_i \Lambda_i(x)$, and $U^{-1}= 1 +  \frac{i}{2} \tau_i \Lambda_i(x)$,

I don't know how as written in the literatures (1) while become

$$A'_\mu=  A_\mu -i [\Lambda,A_\mu]- \frac{1}{g} (\partial_\mu \Lambda)~~~~~~~~~~(2)$$

where $\Lambda=\Lambda_i \frac{\tau_i}{2}$

I tired the following, starting by

$$A'_\mu = (1 -  \frac{i}{2} \tau_i \Lambda_i) ~~ A_\mu^j \frac{\tau_j}{2}~~(1 +  \frac{i}{2} \tau_i \Lambda_i)  - \frac{i}{g} (\partial_\mu -  \frac{i}{2} \tau_i \partial_\mu \Lambda_i) ~~ (1 +  \frac{i}{2} \tau_i \Lambda_i) \\ 
= A_\mu^j \frac{\tau_j}{2} - i [\Lambda,A_\mu] -  (\frac{\tau_i}{2}  \Lambda_i) (A_\mu^j \frac{\tau_j}{2}) ( \frac{\tau_k}{2} \Lambda_k) \\ - \frac{i}{g} [\partial_\mu +  \frac{i}{2} \tau_i \partial_\mu \Lambda_i -  \frac{i}{2} \tau_i \partial_\mu \Lambda_i+  \frac{\tau_i}{2}  \partial_\mu \Lambda_i \frac{\tau_j}{2} \tau_j \Lambda_j] ~~~~~(3)$$

Clearly third, forth, and seventh terms are extra in (3), also fifth and forth terms will cancel each other and we won't able to get a term like ($\frac{1}{g} (\partial_\mu \Lambda)$) in (2), completely a mess !

So any help for the right derivation for (2) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A Lie group element has the form

$$ g = \exp \left( - \frac{i}{2} \tau_i \Lambda_i \right) =  1 - \frac{i}{2} \tau_i \Lambda_i + {\cal O}(\Lambda^2), $$

where $\Lambda$ is the Lie algebra element. You should only keep the linear in $\Lambda$ terms in your calculation. The terms proportional to $\Lambda^2$ are too small to influence the infinitesimal transformation law.